# Whats the right way of implementing service that collects data from multiple services?

Tags: design, architecture

**Overview**

---

I work in a company where we moved to microservice architecture recently and we are constantly growing our services each day, but I found that we have problem maintaining and monitoring all these configuration files spread across the servers and cloud environments. So I thought myself why not start open source project about such use case after trying to search for couple of hours for such tool.

---

**The idea**

---

[image]

---

### **Questions**

As you can see at first glance it sounds really simple, but I wanted to ask you guys what you think?

Comment: I think you've reinvented [file integrity monitoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_integrity_monitoring). Congratulations.

Comment: With my 1 year of experience I haven't heard of it, thanks for the link tho I will have a look :)

Comment: Checkout netflix oss projects before you go too far: https://netflix.github.io/. Eureka achieve service registry/discovery very easy for microservices and it also can monitoring the heart beat of the services. Archaius services quite good as config server. From your diagram, I know you are using .net. In java, spring cloud can achieve most of the patterns just in couple of lines of code. For conf server: https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/, for service discovery https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/20/microservice-registration-and-discovery-with-spring-cloud-and-netflix-s-eureka

Comment: Hmm thing is I don't want to think of this as a microservices related service, we have consul for the health check, registry and fabio for balancing. I can easily include config files in consul as well, but as far as I know(even tho I am so new to this) ITs have the same problems with server configuration themselves.

So initial idea is lightweight monitoring service for config files with easy registration, because I cannot make our ITs install consul or some tool just to monitor their configs on certain server, its not worth it, but if it is some small process, why not?

Comment: If all you want is to push config files to the microservice instances, wouldn't it make more sense to use something like ansible, puppet or chef for this? It's configuration management after all.

Comment: I dont want to push anything, just monitor them from single point per datacentre for instance, I might decide to implement history but this is another story.

Comment: Make your git a configuration "server". During the bootstraping of the services, the config files can be checked out and loaded. You might have as many branches as you need and read only users for the services to check out. You also have history and versioning. Loading changes would take you to reboot the services you need.

Answer (score 1):

While I am new to microservice architecture, I am working on a project with some similarities to your description. My first thought as I read through your notes, was that puppet or chef may be useful.  I have not yet implemented either one, but it seems that with either of them, I will be able to set up specific configurations, which can be watched, and if necessary, changed, or corrected.  This may be overkill for what your are wanting; just sounded like it may be similar to the system I am designing.